# After refresh, firebase Auth current user returns null

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

Here is my code on profile page, this works fine first time when i redirect from login method of AuthService

```
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  if (user != null) {
    this.name = user.displayName;
    this.uid = user.uid;
  } else {
    this.name = "Unknown";
  }
```

However, if I refresh the page or go to any other page and come back to this profile page, currentUser becomes null.

Here is my auth service code.

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import { auth } from "firebase/app";

      async googleSignin() {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
      .then(async () => {
        const provider = new auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
        const credential = await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider);
        this.updateUserData(credential.user);
        this.router.navigate(["/profile"]);
        return;
      });
  }
```

Why i am loosing the currentUser? I even added Persistence.LOCAL too.

Answer (score 16):

When you navigate to a new page, you're reloading the Firebase Authentication SDK. At this point Firebase automatically refreshes the authentication state of the current user, but this may require a roundtrip to the server. And by the time your `firebase.auth().currentUser runs that refresh apparently isn't done yet.

For this reason you should use `onAuthStateChange` to listen for changes, as shown in the documentation on [getting the currently signed in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user != null) {
    this.name = user.displayName;
    this.uid = user.uid;
  } else {
    this.name = "Unknown";
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Frank. Question is how navigating to the site other pages makes the change in authentication? and this happen with seconds. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you rephrase that?

Comment: I have three pages in my app, login, profile and home page. login page, logs in the user. After login i get redirected to profile page. In Profile page 
'''
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser; 

above code works! But if i navigate back to home page or even refresh profile page same line of code give me null for the user. My question is where we loose the user?

Comment: When you load a new page, you reload Firebase Authentication. It automatically refreshes the authentication state of the current user, but this may require a roundtrip to the server. When your `firebase.auth().currentUser` runs that refresh isn't done yet, while with my `onAuthStateChanged` code it is guaranteed to execute your code once the user token has been refreshed.

Answer (score 4):

You can also save the user data to local/session storage in case the service/guard does not recieve it in time because of the async operation.

Comment: sure, you can do that. But bigger question is why Auth state is changing? Why a page refresh looses the current user?

Comment: Because it is a server call under the hood which is async operation it gives back a promise so you have ti promise.then() to wait for the data to arrive or use asyn/await

Comment: I have three pages in my app, login, profile and home page. login page, logs in the user. After login i get redirected to profile page. In Profile page 

const user = firebase.auth().currentUser; 

above code works! But if i navigate back to home page or even refresh profile page same line of code give me null for the user. My question is where we loose the user?

Answer (score 0):

The default persistence strategy is IndexedDB. However, that strategy will not work for me – at least on `localhost:3000`.

Changing the strategy to use local storage fixed it:

```
import { initializeAuth, browserLocalPersistence } from 'firebase/auth';

const auth = initializeAuth(app, {
  persistence: browserLocalPersistence
});
```