# How to get userdata from firestore when refreshing the browser?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I have a Flutter web application where I sign in and navigate to a homepage.
Here I display the name of the user and that is working fine until I refresh my browser.
When I refresh my browser it returns a null value, but when I navigate to another page and back again I retrieve the users name. So I hoping there is another way to do this so I get my users name after refreshing the browser.

When I try to retrieve the users email from `FirebaseAuth` instead of the usersname from `Firestore` it works fine when refreshing the browser. So I think it has something to do with how I retrieve it from `Firestore`.

Here is some of my code:

Main.dart

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  final Future<FirebaseApp> _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp();
  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _initialization,
      builder: (context, snapshot)
    {
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return (MaterialApp(
          home: UserLoginPage(

          ),
        ));
      }
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
        print('CONNECTED');
        return StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
              return MaterialApp(
                home: snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null
                    ? const UserHomePage()
                    : const UserLoginPage(),
                routes: {
                  UserLoginPage.id: (context) => const UserLoginPage(),
                 
                  UserHomePage.id: (context) => const UserHomePage(),
             
                },
                debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,

              );
            }
        );
      }
      return Column();
    });
  }
}
```

HomePage

```
class _UserHomePageState extends State<UserHomePage> {
  final scaffoldkey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;


  Future _getUserData() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user?.uid)
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) async {
      if (snapshot.exists) {
        setState(() {
          name = snapshot.data()!['Navn'];
          print(name!);
        });
      }
    });
  }


  DateTime now = DateTime.now();


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getUserData();


  }

  //String
  String? name = '';
  String? formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(DateTime.now());





  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var appBarHeight = kToolbarHeight; 
    
    return Scaffold(
        key: scaffoldkey,
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(119, 221, 167, 1),
          title: const Text(
            'Test',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Poppins',
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 22,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          centerTitle: true,

        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        drawer: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: appBarHeight + 1),
          child: Drawer(
            child: ListView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text(name!),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),

              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Text('Hei, $name!',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),

              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

}
```

Comment: can you check this stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58262209/after-refresh-firebase-auth-current-user-returns-null) ,[blog](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-is-my-currentuser-null-in-firebase-auth-4701791f74f0)  and this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/manage-users)

Comment: I will check these, thank you